# How can I pass in an element's ID on an ng-hover event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an element like so:

```
<div id="one" ng-mouseover="showDefinition()"> Some Text</div>
<div id="one" ng-mouseover="showDefinition()"> Some Text</div>
<div id="one" ng-mouseover="showDefinition()"> Some Text</div>
```

When I hover over each respective element, it fires the showDefinition function:

```
    scope.showDefinition = function showDefinition() {
        console.log("youve hovered over the id : + <element's id>");
        }
```

How can I pass in the element id in which the hover was triggered?

Comment: Look at the angular docs for `$event`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scope.showDefinition = function showDefinition(e) {
  console.log("you've hovered over the id" : + e.target.id);
}
```

and in the HTML

```
<div id="one" ng-mouseover="showDefinition($event)"> Some Text</div>
```

**Plunkr**: https://plnkr.co/edit/CW9kXLzc23xcWlA5EJzm?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Jim Cote is right, you can pass in the `$event` to your ng-mouseover like so:

`<div id="one" ng-mouseover="showDefinition($event)"> Some Text</div>`

[$event documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/guide/expression#-event-)

The $event is basically a [jquery (or jqlite) event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

You will also want to ensure that you don't reuse an id in your html, as that will mess things up.

Your code could end up being something like this:

```
<div id="one" ng-mouseover="showDefinition($event)"> Some Text</div>
<div id="two" ng-mouseover="showDefinition($event)"> Some Text</div>
<div id="three" ng-mouseover="showDefinition($event)"> Some Text</div>



scope.showDefinition = function showDefinition(event) {
    console.log("youve hovered over the id :" + event.target.id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for event documentation link. Sometime ago I need this documentation, but I don't know the name "$event" to search

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as argument itself :) Don't even need `event` object

```
<div id="one" ng-mouseover="showDefinition('one')"> Some Text</div>
<div id="two" ng-mouseover="showDefinition('two')"> Some Text</div>
```

And in the controller,

```
scope.showDefinition = function showDefinition(id) {
    console.log("youve hovered over the id : " + id);
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/OxM5PE4gNtSzpVLnz7Tm?p=preview

Comment: I believe this is a better answer rather than using $event, I myself don't want to use $event for I guess "complexity", but @paritosh  can you help me understand why not to use $event?

Comment: Using `$event` is more powerful than just passing in the id string. You have access to the entire event object and this is what you get in vanilla JavaScript so I don't think "complexity" is fair here. Besides, you are duplicating your code passing in the id to the function like this. Say you change the id from "one" to "first". Now you have to change all your event handlers.

Comment: @AshishRanjan: I am not suggesting you to avoid `$event`. Just the first thought came to my mind seeing the question. If you are not going to need `$event`, why do you `need` to pass it? It's a debatable point. All can have different opinion. Better to keep things simple!

Comment: The $event approach is a bit more complex, because the method needs an indirect parameter "e.target.id"... it's not too clean when you read the function definition.

Comment: @adam-beck: right! agree, but usually we don't change the ids! its a little duplication in code, but then I am also saving memory!

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo but it really isn't the `id` of the element. It's a completely different String that happens to have the same value. 1 spelling mistake and this breaks without error. 

@AshishRanjan "usually" is the key word. And spelling mistakes can still happen. The memory argument is almost a non-existent one. You aren't saving much. But, coding is both art & science. Choose what you feel is best suited.

Comment: I think angular business is far from DOM model. If I have a method doAction(), I hope that method will receive a parameter relative to action. I like your approach with $event, because the title of question is "how to get the id". But on my code, I prefer something like doOpen('customers'), for example. Rarely I define the id property.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you don't like the fact that the callback function isn't receiving "just" the id? If that is the case you don't have to pass the entire `$event` object. You could very well pass in `ng-mouseover="showDefinition($event.target.id)`. That way your callback will only be working with the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Working code snippet attached

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.showDefinition = function showDefinition($event) {
        console.log("youve hovered over the id :" + $event.target.id);
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div id="one" ng-mouseover="showDefinition($event)"> Some Text</div>
<div id="two" ng-mouseover="showDefinition($event)"> Some Text</div>
<div id="three" ng-mouseover="showDefinition($event)"> Some Text</div>
  </div>
```